# Search columns for lowest value (in each row) and return header and value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, min, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I want to search a range for the lowest price of an item in a row and return that price as well as the store (header).  Ideally, this would be an `ARRAYFORMULA` as the list will be probably grow constantly.

I've tried a combination of `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH`, but just can't seem to get it to all come together.

[image]

Here's a link to [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c8ulLMuIVI-ciCOTABX8ytGsKkuacnvPqT0SdhoJtBc/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:G),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 "min(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")", ))&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image]

and headers:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I2:I, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:D="",,"♠"&B2:D&"♦"&B1:D1))
 ,,99^99)),,99^99), "♠")), "♦"), 2, 0)))
```